# Angular JS and external libraries

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a third party JavaScript library (not Angular) and I would like to use its methods/objects from Angular.

I know I can place a `<script type="text/javascript">` into an angular HTML view and use those methods there but that's really ugly.

How else could this be done?

Comment: include the library in your index.html before the <script link to angular and it should be available

Comment: +1 Cathal. Besides, is that a public librairie? If it is, consider checking out if an Angular module is available.

Comment: It's Braintree library (https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/javascript) and they hasn't an Angular module. I tried to put it before anything else but I don't know how to register it as Angular Module/Dependency and to use it on a controller for example.

Comment: Well, you could wrap it inside a angular module, but then it wouldn't really be global. As Cathal says, just include it before including Angular and you should be fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh well, I found it, just attach to the `$window` and you are done.

As written here: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+node/sdk/client/setup

"**The SDK will appear as braintree on the global window object.**"

So from your controller (for example) you can simply use `$window.braintree` and you got everything you need from Braintree client library.

To load the Dropin you can simply use this:

```
angular.module('app').controller('YourController', ['$scope', '$window',
    function ($scope, $window) {

        $window.braintree.setup('CLIENTTOKEN', 'dropin', {
            container: 'dropin'
        });

    }
]);
```

Comment: the link provided changed

Answer (score 5):

Include it before Angular and you should be fine

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="braintree.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js">
```

Using it with angular should not be a problem.

Can you create a Plunker or JSFiddle of a simple problem?

Sample answer of how to use the two together: [Encrypting credit card details using AngularJS in Braintree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985531/encrypting-credit-card-details-using-angularjs-in-braintree)